# Problems with Routing, Render and CSS in Flask

Tags: python, flask

**Problem**

I have the `css files` in /static/ and the `html files` in /templates/.

When I use simple routing, its works well.

```
@app.route('/newuser', methods=['GET'])
    def newuserform():
        return render_template("newuser.html")
```

But in this code, Flask doesn't render correctly the .CSS files, why?

```
@app.route('/new/user', methods=['GET'])
def newuserform():
    return render_template("newuser.html")
```

Loading .css files in html,

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the link as

```
<link href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or better use static urls generator for Jinja2

```
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
```

Comment: what is the best use? jinja2 using url_for or href="../static/css" ?
My question is Jinja2 method is a workaround?

Comment: Best use is the Jinja2 url_for. You can change the static directory to anything you need. Thus the same application can use different stylesheets based on the settings file.

Comment: Always use `url_for`.

Comment: Use `url_for`, but in case where you need to specify the URL directly, use `/static` rather than `../static`. If you added another level to the page's URL (e.g., `/new/user/add`), the latter wouldn't work anymore.